# Vector connecting terminal points of two vectors

Tags: vectors

How do you find the components of a vector that connects the terminal points of two other vectors, whose components are known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the components of the source vector from the components of the destination vector.

Because vectors do have a location, you can assume that the two vectors start from `(0, 0, 0)` (for 3D) and therefore their component distances, are the same as the coordinates of their terminal points `(a, b, c)`.

Then, you make a vector connecting the points by simply finding the difference between the coordinates to get each component.

e.g.

```
X = <a, b, c>
Y = <d, e, f>
Z = <a-d, b-e, f-c>
```